# Dynamically creating/accessing the Chart while visualizing the dashboard in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

We are trying to display two pie Charts in the default Dashboard and when user clicks on one of these pie-charts the data-table of the selected pie-chart should overlay/override on other pie-chart dynamically.

For example:

- The dashboard displays two pie-charts by default. The pie-chart on
  the left side display the employee and salaries data. The right side
  pie-chart will have the employee and locations data.
- When user clicks on the left pie-chart, the right pie-chart should be
  overlay/override by a bar-chart OR data-table which contains the
  employees' hierarchy, organization hierarchy with salaries. And user
  clicks outside the pie-charts the default view with two pie-charts
  should display.
- Similarly when the user clicks on the right side pie-chart, the left
  side pie-chart should be overlay/override by different bar-chart OR
  data-table which shows the employees and their working locations.

Please find the attached screenshots in reference to the above example.

[Default Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyGSR.jpg)

[After the user clicks on the left side pie chart in the default dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoG0H.jpg)

We tried available filters but they works with in the graph/chart, but not overriding existing graph with another graph.
Please guide us on how to achieve the dashboard.

Comment: This question would be more useful to other users if it asked more for an explanation of a concept or method instead of how to do your particular project.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current native charts and feature set does not enable changing chart types on the fly in view mode.

That being said, you can create your own customized chart in javascript that will let you do this.

Alternatively, if clicking does not require filtering of the data, you put a transparent box on top of each pie chart and hyperlink to separate pages with the correct charts.